# Classic ASP code injected buttons not firing jQuery click events

Tags: jquery

I am using two classic asp pages and one jquery .js file. Now, my main asp page contains an insert button in the markup and a place holder Div that contains classic asp markup, with two buttons, that has been dynamically injected into it from the content of a second asp page. The main asp page makes reference to the application's external jquery file. The problem I am having is that the button on the main asp page triggers a jquery button click function just find; however, the two buttons contained on the second page's injected code does not fire their jquery click events.

Main asp Default page code (Submit button and jquery work fine):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Customer CRUD</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/regras.js"></script>
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>View Company</h1>   
        <hr/>       
        <div id="InjectionPlaceholder"></div>
        <hr/>
    </center>
    <div id="box" >
        <br/>
         &nbsp; Name: <input type="text" id="ContactName1" />
        <hr/>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;Address: <input type="text" id="address1" />
        <hr/>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <center><div id="ErrorMsg"></div></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Second asp page used for the code injection and it's classic asp functions (It's two buttons don't fire the jquery events):

```
<%        
    '' This page gets injected into the main Default asp page. On the page are also the Delete and Update asp calls
    Dim CustomerID
    <%
    ''======================================================
    '' The database is called to build the customer table used for injection 
    '' Buttons don't call the jquery functions.
    ''======================================================    
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    sql = "SELECT * FROM customers"
    rs.Open sql, bco 
    If not rs.eof then
    %><table border="1">
    <%
    Do while not rs.eof
    CustomerID = rs("CustomerID")
    %>                       
    <tr>
    <td>Company Name:<span id="CompanyName1"> <%=rs("CompanyName")%></span></td>    
    <td>align='center'>Contact Name: <span id='ContactName1'><%=rs("ContactName")%></span></td>
    <td>Address: <%=rs("Address")%></td>
     <td><button id="Update" onclick="updateClick(<%=CustomerID%>)">Update</button></td>
    <td><button id="Delete" onclick="deleteClick(<%=CustomerID%>)">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>              
    <%
    rs.movenext
    loop
    %>
    </table>
    <%
    Else
    Response.Write("No Records Found.")
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    %>
```

The contents of the external jquery file:

```
    $(function () {
        console.log('Company JavaScript!');
        //SELECT
        try {
            GetCustomers();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

        // This Button event is the one that works. It calls the insertClick event.
        $("#submit").click(insertClick);

        // This is the function that injects the markup from the Injection.asp 
        // into the Default.asp page. It is called in each button click event.
        //SELECT
        function GetCustomers() {

            $.post('Injection.asp', function (data) {
                $("#InjectionPlaceholder").html(data);

            });   
        };

        //This is one of the injected page click event that does not work. It's 
        //button is in the injected code
        function deleteClick(CompanyName) {
            alert("Test1"); //Alert doesn't get called
            //DELETE
            try {
                console.log('Remove Company =' + CompanyName);
                $.post('Injection.asp?delete=' + CompanyName);
                Refresh = false;
                GetCustomers();
                window.location.replace("http://localhost:82/Refresh.asp");

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }

        // This function works correctly. It's button is in the Default.asp 
        // page.
        function insertClick() {    
        //INSERT
            try {
                var nameIns = $("#ContactName1").val();
                var addressIns = $("#Address1").val();
                if (nameIns !== "" && addressIns !== "") {
                    $.post("Injection.asp.asp?ContactName" + nameIns + "&Address=" + addressIns);
                    $.post('Injection.asp', function (data) {
                        Refresh = false;
                        GetCustomers();
                        $("#CustomerName1").val("");
                        $("#Address1").val("");                     window.location.replace("http://localhost:82/Refresh.asp");
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Insert Failed");
                }   

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }

        //This is one of the injected page click event that does not work. It's 
        //button is in the injected code
        //UPDATE
        function updateClick(company) {
            var nameUpd;
            var addressUpd;
            alert("Test2"); //Alert doesn't get called
            nameUpd = prompt("Enter the contact name:", "");
            addressUpd = prompt("Enter the contact address: ", "");

            if ((nameUpd === "" || nameUpd === null) && (addressUpd === "" || addressUpd === null)) {
                alert("Invalid input");

            } else {
                try {
                    console.log("Name: " + nameUpd + ", address: " + addressUpd + ", company: " + company);

                    var pageUpd = 'Injection.asp?CompanyName=' + company + '&ContactName=' + nameUpd + '&Address=' + addressUpd;
                    $.post(pageUpd, function (data) {
                        console.log(pageUpd);
                        Refresh = false;
                        GetCustomers();
                    window.location.replace("http://localhost:82/Refresh.asp");
                    });

                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }    
            };    
        };   
    });
```

Comment: JavaScript has no knowledge of the server-side code.  What is the resulting HTML?  Show just the code which produces the problem.

Comment: Instead of assigning the JS function like this onclick="updateClick(<%=CustomerID%>)">, you should do $(document).on("click","#Delete",function(){updateClick();}); since the content is loaded dynamically, it will not fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just at a quick glance, there are several things wrong here.  Specifically there are two critical errors:

First, this isn't going to do what you expect:

```
onclick="updateClick()"
```

Because the `updateClick` function *doesn't exist* in the window's global scope.  So you're very likely getting an error on your browser's development console which is telling you exactly this.  Instead, use the event binding *that you already use*.  For example, see how you bind this:

```
$("#submit").click(insertClick);
```

That's how you bind an event in jQuery.  So use that for your other events as well.  For example:

```
$("#Update").click(updateClick);
```

**Or**, if the elements are being inserted after the initial jQuery code executes, use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", "#Update", updateClick);
```

*However*, the *second* problem here is that you're re-using `id` values in your page.  This is invalid HTML so the JavaScript behavior would be undefined.  Specifically, the `id`-based selector isn't going to know *which* element you're trying to identify.  Instead, use a class and bind to all of the elements:

```
<button class="update">Update</button>
```

and:

```
$(".update").click(updateClick);
```

**Or**:

```
$(document).on("click", ".update", updateClick);
```

Once these errors are fixed, you should have a working click event.  However, now you have the additional issue of needing to pass the `<%=CustomerID%>` value to those events.  Instead of passing it as a function argument, set it as a data property on the element so that the handler can grab it dynamically from the clicked element.  Something like this:

```
<button class="update" data-customerID="<%=CustomerID%>">Update</button>
```

Then in the handler function you can get that value:

```
function updateClick() {
    var company = $(this).data('customerID');
    // the rest of your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When elements added dynamically to the DOM jQuery can't attach an event handler to them. A different approach is to attach the event handler to a parent element that 
"statically" rendered to the DOM (or to the document if theres no such parent) and pass the child element.

example:

```js
$('#click1').click(function(e){
  var child = '<div id="child">Child, click me</div>';
  $('#root').append(child);
});

$('#root').on('click','#child', function(e){
  console.log('child clicked');
});

/* this wont work!
$('#child').click(function(e){
  console.log('child clicked');
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div id="click1">Add element</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: they do get inserted dynamically via the js `GetCustomers` method if i understand correctly (ajax)

Comment: You're right, I'd missed that.  The code presented has several problems it would seem.

Comment: looks like it yeah. you did mention most of them, but for the specific problem the OP mentioned i think it's the dynamic element added